# Trim characters from list elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, trim

I have the below code:

```
    public class HtmlParser {

private Document doc;
private List<String>dataList;

public HtmlParser(Properties configuration) throws IOException {

    String url = configuration.getProperty("url");
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    this.dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Elements tableRows = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for (Element tr : tableRows){
        dataList.add(tr.text()+"\n");
    }

    System.out.println(this.dataList);
```

which prints out the following:

```
[Flights on time 93%
, Within 1 hour 99%
, FLIGHT FROM TO DEPART ARRIVE STATUS
, FR 2111 Manchester Paphos 06:25 13:20 Landed 13:40
, FR 8582 London Stansted Thessaloniki 06:30 11:45 Landed
, FR 6093 Gran Canaria Milan Bergamo 06:35 12:05 Landed Early 11:47
, FR 4002 Lanzarote Milan Bergamo 07:15 12:25 Landed
, FR 2482 Leeds Bradford Riga 07:20 11:55 Landed
, FR 5212 Marrakesh Paris Beauvais 07:20 11:50 Landed Early 11:40
, FR 1041 Gran Canaria Stockholm Skavsta 07:45 14:30 On Time
, FR 6342 Rome Fiumicino Barcelona El Prat 08:15 10:00 Estimated Arrival 14:35
, OPERATING FROM FIUMICINO DUE TO WEATHER DIVERSION - PASSENGERS TO BE COACHED TO FIUMICINO AIRPORT
, FR 4172 Porto Frankfurt Hahn 08:15 11:45 Landed
, FR 4883 Rome Fiumicino Cagliari 08:20 09:30 Landed 12:50
, FR 7062 Dublin Alicante 08:30 12:25 Landed Early 12:05
, FR 1015 Tenerife Sth Stockholm Skavsta 08:30 15:15 On Time
, FR 7158 Dublin Madrid 08:45 12:35 Landed Early 12:15
, FR 8405 London Stansted Wroclaw 08:50 11:50 Landed
, FR 2065 Porto Dortmund 08:55 12:30 Landed
, FR 1031 Tenerife Sth Oslo Rygge 09:00 15:30 On Time
, FR 9283 Faro London Stansted 09:05 11:55 Landed Early 11:46
, FR 3071 London Stansted Comiso 09:05 13:15 Landed Early 13:10
, FR 3006 London Stansted Rome Ciampino 09:10 12:35 Landed
]
```

Firstly, I want to remove the , and the whitespace from the start of the rows and have the text starting with FR. I've tried `dataList.remove(0)` but it doesn't work. Oddly enough, in the console display, all the rows are separated with a new line before each "," but it isn't showing up here.

I'm looking to select a particular row by keyword like Stanstead, and add text into the middle of it like "Arrival Time:" etc, but I'm having trouble here.

I'm reasonably new to Java and learning as i go here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hints to help you learn:

> Firstly, I want to remove the , and the whitespace from the start of the rows and have the text starting with FR.

Read about the `trim` and `substring` methods of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  In fact, I recommend reading that entire page ... and also the pages for [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) ...

Bear in mind that all String objects are immutable, so `trim` and so on all work by creating *new* strings.  So to get the updates to "stick" you would need to replace each list element with the updated value.

(Also see below!)

> I've tried `dataList.remove(0)` but it doesn't work.

That method removes an entry from a list.

> Oddly enough, in the console display, all the rows are separated with a new line before each "," but it isn't showing up here.

Actually it is / they are.  Those are is what is causing the line breaks before each comma in your output ... and the commas themselves!  When you call this:

```
    System.out.println(this.dataList);
```

the list is being formatted by the list object's `toString()` method.  This is what is adding the square brackets and the mysterious `", "` stuff.

Before you start writing code to edit those mysterious characters out of the strings, check that they are *really* there ... and not just an artefact of the way you printed the list.

> I'm looking to select a particular row by keyword like Stanstead, and add text into the middle of it like "Arrival Time:" etc, but I'm having trouble here.

Iterate over the list, and call `contains` on each String.  The javadoc is at the place linked above ...